# Programatically remove "hover state" from element on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I've got an element on a webpage, with a defined set of `:hover` styles. On mobile, this causes the "sticky hover" effect, where a touch on the element will cause the hover to apply, which is then removed when the user touches somewhere else on the page.

This is desirable for me - I'm not looking to prevent this, but I need a way to prgramatically remove that hover state once a user has interacted with it (to return the element to it's original state).

Is that possible? I've tried a `$('some-other-element').click()` but nothing will remove that state aside from manually clicking elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Could try changing `focus`

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I'd tried that - no luck there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using :hover, make it a class such as .hover.

Then add and remove it using jQuery such as

```
$(".your-button").on("mouseenter", function()
{
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});

$(".your-button").on("mouseleave", function()
{
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});


// Explicitly remove it
$(".your-button").removeClass("hover");
```

Edit: also if you want to use the click method. You may need to make it click on something that is focusable.

Lastly you could also try using the :active requirement.

Comment: That's not a bad idea TBH.. not sure why the downvote happened but I think this coudl work..